# Is there a way for me to choose a set of 3 preferences for classmates to obtain the same classes every time?

Tags: networking, matching, allocation

Students are being distributed to classes. Each class has 10 students, each student can select 3 other students and at least one of these is guaranteed to be in their class, is there a way for these selections to be manipulated so 6 students are always in the same class together? More than 6 student's selections may be used if necessary.

I tried myself and only found preferences for 7 students that meant groups of 4 and 3 would be together, but no way to guarantee all 6/7. I was wondering if it is possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.